# MVC 3 edit view for certain fields only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this model:

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    [Key]
    public  int ExchangeRateID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Currency:")]
    public  string Currency { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public  decimal Rate { get; set; }
}
```

The "Create" view is working fine, but when I am in the edit view, I only want the Currency property to be displayed, and not editable. How should I do this? If I create another "view-only" model for this class, then I would omit the "Currency" property and would not be able to display it.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>ExchangeRate</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ExchangeRateID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Currency)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Currency)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rate)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Changing @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Currency) to @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Currency) doesn't work because the model state becomes invalid when it posts back to the controller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could add

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Currency)
```

in your form and then use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.Currency)
```

to display the readonly value of the currency property.  That way when you post the value will be sent along in the posted model.

Comment: This also works in combination with Twitter bootstrap, e.g. using the following in the view: `<span class="uneditable-input">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductName)</span>`

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue=true)]
```

Then show the editor, not the display (use `EditorFor`).

This displays the value read-only, but adds a hidden input so that the posted state is valid.

Comment: Tried this with MVC 4 but didn't work for me and resulted in hidden-only. Nothing is displayed with EditorFor(). I may have overlooked something, though. I went for @mreyeros 's solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

To display the currency but not edit it try

```
@Html.Label("Currency", Model.Currency)
```

if you also need to post the currency value back to the controller try

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Currency)
```

I hope this helps.